# Test the continuity or discontinuity of the following function by calculating ..

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

Test the continuity or discontinuity of the following functions by calculating the left hand limits, right hand limits and the values of the functions at points specified:
$$f(x)=\dfrac {1}{x-2} \textrm { at } x\neq 2$$.

The function is not defined at $x=2$ so, $x\neq 2$.
Then how to check the continuity at that point?

Answer (score 1):

$x\longmapsto \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is also undefined at $x=0$, but you can define a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ on $\mathbb R\backslash \{0\}$.

In your case, you need to check if $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)$ exist and are equals. If they are, you can extend the function by continuity (and thus, we can roughly speaking say that it's continuous at $x=2$), otherwise, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Let from lhl we have$ f (x^-)=lim_{h\to 0}\frac {1}{2-h-2}=-\infty,f (x^{+})=lim_{h\to 0}\frac {1}{2+h-2}=+\infty$ so it isnt continuous. Simple way would be to answer is $\frac {1}{x} $ continuous at $0$. Uf you know this then its just that function is shifted by $2$ units towards right.